# Keras ConvLSTM Regressor throwing value error at dense layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on building a regressor.  Currently the regressor will accept information through the network it appears up until the final dense layer when it throws an error.  I'm new to these types of LSTM and would appreciate some help throubleshooting.  I've looked through a few articles and haven't found anything that seems to work.

```
def generate_arrays(arrays=None, targets=None):
    from random import shuffle
    while True:
        available_ids = list(range(len(arrays)))
        shuffle(available_ids)
        for i in available_ids:

            frames = []
            for image in arrays[i]:
                # load the image
                img = Image.open(image_path + image)
                # convert image to numpy array
                img = np.asarray(img) / 255
                height = 220
                width = 220
                dim = (width, height)
                img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
                # add to bigger np array
                frames.append(img)
            frames = np.array(frames)

            frames = frames.reshape(-1, 3, 220, 220, 3)

            target = targets[i]
            yield (frames, category)

def build_model(frames=seq_len, channels=3, pixels_x=220, pixels_y=220):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        ConvLSTM2D(filters=10
                   , kernel_size=(2,2)
                   , data_format='channels_last'
                   , return_sequences = False
                   , activation='relu', input_shape=(frames, pixels_x, pixels_y, channels))
                )
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

    model.compile(    
        loss = "mse",
        optimizer = optimizer,
        metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

    return model

def evaluate_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y):
    # define model
    model = build_model()
    model.summary()
    # fit network
    model.fit_generator(
        generate_arrays(train_x, train_y)
        , steps_per_epoch = len(train_x)

        , validation_data = generate_arrays(test_x, test_y)
        , validation_steps = len(test_x)

        , epochs = 100
        , verbose = 1
        , shuffle = False
        , initial_epoch = 0
        )
```

The model summary is as such:

[image]

Now, the error I'm getting appears to be the generic value error that means that something isn't getting passed correctly but I cannot figure out what it is...

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_47 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Comment: Please share your `generate_arrays` method. Also you realize that your Dense layer `dense_46` is huge right?.

Comment: Edited for adding generate_arrays function.  And yes, dense_46 will be large.  However, I tested and shrinking it will not change the result of this error.

Comment: Yes, the error won't go away but you will get slower training speeds (or even OOM errors). What're the shapes of `train_x`, `train_y` , `test_x`, `test_y` ?

Comment: 800 for train and roughly 300 for test (approximated)

Comment: You need to find the actual shapes. I'm suspecting that you are passing a scalar as your target to the model instead of a (data size, 1) array.

Comment: My train_x and test_x are passed with a shape of (1, 3, 220, 220, 3) after reshaping.  The target may be the issue as I am passing a scalar.  Upon further research I'm also worried that my train_x may be wrong as I believe the shape should be (None, 3, 220, 220, 3) according to this article.  With that in mind, and with the shape of the "x" variables, would the target be a shape of (1, 3, 1)?  ((samples, time_steps, 1))

https://medium.com/neuronio/an-introduction-to-convlstm-55c9025563a7

Comment: It's just that your target is the problem. Your target needs to have a scalar for **every** data point in `train/test_x`. So if you pass a (1,3,220, 220, 3) image then you need a target of size (1,1) (i.e. not (1,3,1)  according to your current setup). The none dimension means that it can take any arbitrary sized batch (including size 1) so that's not a problem.

Comment: If my train/test x has 3 data points (as per my shape) wouldn't the target need to also be long?  Shape of (3,)?

Comment: That's depending on the problem you're trying to solve. If you have a target for each time step, then you need to set `return_sequences=True` in the ConvLSTM2D layer and should flatten the output while leaving the time axis in tact. Right now you only get the last output of the CONVLSTM layer therefore the model only expects a single target per datapoint

Comment: Okay I misunderstood, thank you for the clarification.  I appreciate the help and think I'll be able to solve this!  I wish the errors were more useful for troubleshooting